# Error - expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'

Tags: sql, ansible, yaml

I am struggling with a SQL query in a YAML file. I have tested my SQL query in my database, which works perfectly.

This is my query in my Ansible file:

```
shell: "{{ scrub_command }} -c \"UPDATE project_record SET meta=jsonb_set(meta, '{"email"}', concat('"', meta->>'email', '.not"')::jsonb) WHERE meta->>'email' IS NOT NULL AND meta->>'email' NOT ILIKE '%@email.somethingelse.com' AND meta->>'email' NOT ILIKE '%@something.com';\""
```

I can see that in the editor, my query is not ending properly as the `\"`  has a different color from the opening `\"`).

If I take out the part:

```
concat('"', meta->>'email', '.not"')::jsonb)
```

the query is closing properly.

I have tried playing with the query and testing it in YAML lint website, but I can't find a way for my YAML file to accept my query.

The error I get when running my script is:

```
Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n  expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
```

The YAML lint website would give this error:

```
did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 1
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `concat('\"', meta->>'email', '.not\"')::jsonb)` - just the first tihng I spotted, but there mgith be more errors in your quoting.

Comment: I have just tried and in the editor it is not closing but the YAML lint error changed to `did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 3 `

Comment: yeah, you havethe same  mistake at `meta, '{"email"}', concat(` , needs to be `meta, '{\"email\"}', concat(` at least, if not `meta, '{\\\"email\\\"}', concat(`. Check your quoting!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not YAML valid. Can you try with :
`shell: "{{ scrub_command }} -c \"UPDATE project_record SET meta=jsonb_set(meta, '{\"email\"}', concat('\"', meta->>'email', '.not\"')::jsonb) WHERE meta->>'email' IS NOT NULL AND meta->>'email' NOT ILIKE '%@email.somethingelse.com' AND meta->>'email' NOT ILIKE '%@something.com';\""`

This one is valid according to http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: Yupp, @AlexisFilipozzi found the one I   did and one more. However I do think that you might need to double-escape the " inside the SQL (`\\\"`  -<yes, tripple backslash) so they are still escaped once when scrub_command is run. This reply might be valid YAML, but will likely not pass the second step, which is running scrub_command

Comment: Of course! This passes the YAML lint, Now I am wondering about what @JohannesH. says. Can you explain where you want to put those `\\\` please?

Comment: You should try with `shell: "{{ scrub_command }} -c \"UPDATE project_record SET meta=jsonb_set(meta, '{\\\"email\\\"}', concat('\\\"', meta->>'email', '.not\\\"')::jsonb) WHERE meta->>'email' IS NOT NULL AND meta->>'email' NOT ILIKE '%@email.somethingelse.com' AND meta->>'email' NOT ILIKE '%@something.com';\""`

Comment: The problem is - if you escape them all once, it will result in `... -c "UPDATE project_record SET meta=jsonb_set(meta, '{"email"}', concat('"', meta->>'email', '.not"')::jsonb) WHERE meta->>'email' IS NOT NULL AND meta->>'email' NOT ILIKE '%@email.somethingelse.com' AND meta->>'email' NOT ILIKE '%@something.com';"`, meaning the " everywhere will always end the outermost quote. But it all has to be one argument, so everything has to be within the quotes.

Comment: See @AlexisFilipozzi's comment above mine for what you SHOULD do.

Comment: A simplier and more readable solution (if possible) could be to :
  - add a bash script file using the template module of ansible. This template whould contains your command as you would execute it on the machine (probably `{{ scrub_command }} -c "UPDATE project_record SET meta=jsonb_set(meta, '{"email"}', concat('"', meta->>'email', '.not"')::jsonb) WHERE meta->>'email' IS NOT NULL AND meta->>'email' NOT ILIKE '%@email.somethingelse.com' AND meta->>'email' NOT ILIKE '%@something.com';"`)
- add a task to ensure this file is executable
- then run your script running the remote command

Comment: Ok, so I ran the Ansible script and it did not work with the solution `'{\\\"email"\\\}'` ...   I am going to try your other option @AlexisFilipozzi    By the way, it was giving me the same error.

Comment: Guys, I found out why it was not working. The solution `'{\\\"email"\\\}'` was good, I forgot to change the name in Ansible. To explain better, I wrote the same query in the name part in my Ansible script, and it needed the escape quotes as well. Now my script is working fine. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to put scalars that have both single and double quotes themselves into YAML is by using a block style scalars. That is a scalar that is indicated by the `|` or `>` character. In the block style (`|`) none of the characters in the scalar are interpreted, even newlines are newlines:

```
shell: |-
    {{ scrub_command }} -c \"UPDATE project_record SET meta=jsonb_set(meta, '{"email"}', concat('"', meta->>'email', '.not"')::jsonb) WHERE meta->>'email' IS NOT NULL AND meta->>'email' NOT ILIKE '%@email.somethingelse.com' AND meta->>'email' NOT ILIKE '%@something.com';\"
```

In folded style single newlines are replaced by a space so you can make things a bit more readable:

```
shell: >-
    {{ scrub_command }} -c \"UPDATE project_record 
    SET meta=jsonb_set(meta, '{"email"}', concat('"', meta->>'email', '.not"')::jsonb)
     WHERE meta->>'email' IS NOT NULL AND meta->>'email' NOT ILIKE '%@email.somethingelse.com' AND meta->>'email'
     NOT ILIKE '%@something.com';\"
```

In both the second line should be exactly (including backslashes that have no special meaning in these block style YAML scalars, but of course do for the shell that executes the string loaded from the scalar).

The `-` after `|` resp. `>` is necessary to get rid of the trailing newline.